# How to retrieve http file list from folder and download in R

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I would like to get a list of downloadable files from an http website (data.mesonet.unl), and then download them.  How do I do this?  I've tried using the following code. but it just returns a bunch of html that has the actual href links embedded in it.  There must be something out there to easily do this automatically - I just can't find it.  The following is my basic code, and all variants I've tried basically do the same thing, with no real results. Thanks in advance.

```
library(RCurl)
url <- 'https://data.mesonet.unl.edu/data/alda_5nw/'
files <- getURLContent(url)
```

Comment: You need to scrape the folder and file information from that listing. I suggest using `rvest` to parse out the parts you need. (Recognize that while it looks like a simple file listing, the actual format varies depending on the server itself, such as apache-vs-nginx-vs-IIS, etc, as well as options set by the sysadmin. I don't know of a function or package in R that automatically parses all of that for you. I don't imagine the `rvest` code would be that difficult, though.)

Comment: For instance, `library(rvest); sess <- session("https://data.mesonet.unl.edu/data/alda_5nw"); html_table(sess)[[1]]` returns a `data.frame` that is a good start for iterating over directories for a manual "recursion" down the directories.

Comment: {Rcrawler} might be worth a try: https://github.com/salimk/Rcrawler#how-to-use-rcrawler